# Instant preview does not work in LyX 2.1.2 on OS X 10.10 yosemite

Tags: lyx, mac

After upgrading to OS X 10.10 yosemite, the instant preview of LyX seems broken --- it no longer works. I have tried to reconfigure the LyX both directly and launched through terminal, and neither works. Anyone has the same problem and has a solution for that? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out the posting [Lyx 2.x: Document Class Not Available - Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite PB 3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203810/5001)? It may apply to your posting as well.

Comment: Yes. I have seen the post and it solved the other problem -- Document Class Not Available. Now LyX at least works, but it still does not have preview, which makes it not that pretty when typing maths.. Thanks though.

Comment: Same for me here. Got rid of the Class not available error but instant preview is still only accessible  through Terminal. Reinstalled both GS and XQuartz.

Comment: They fixed it in 2.1.2.1.

Answer (score 3):

For me it works if you run LyX from the terminal. (I.e., not just reconfigure it from the terminal, but run & load your file).

Edit: to be clear, running from the terminal means opening LyX with this command:

`$ /Applications/LyX.app/Contents/MacOS/lyx`

If you open LyX and run reconfigure, this will solve some problems, but not the instant preview.

However, if you run LyX from the terminal, and open a document, then (in my case) that instance of LyX **will** render instant preview correctly. It's a nuisance but it works.

Comment: I've tried to document some problems with Yosemite here, since it has problems that affect many applications. It includes an example of launching from Terminal, which I suspect is what @TomCunningham means. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208181/why-did-my-tex-related-gui-program-stop-working-in-mac-os-x-yosemite

Comment: @ThomasTong If Tom's answer solved your problem, you can mark the question as solved by accepting his answer, which you do by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 and LyX Version 2.2.3.

So for configure I install with home brew this recommended programs:

```
brew update
brew cask install basictex
brew cask install texmaker
```

I use the basictex because has everything I needed, the mactex is very big.
If you prefer install everything so, install the mactex:

```
brew cask install mactex
```

Go to the menu **LyX > Preferences > File handling > File formats**:

1. format choose "PDF (pdflatex)"
2. set viewer to "open -a Preview"

**Apply, Save and close**.

So on the menu I click on **Tools > Reconfigure**.

Then the LyX reconfigure automatically everything on terminal.
Wait for a while until reconfigure everything.

So after this click on **Document > (Visualize Other formats) > PDF (pdflatex)** or **CMD + R**(*this command isn't accessible everytime so I recommend to get the first option*).

And wait for a while and shows the pdf with Pre-visual.app.
Very nice and I haven't needed to install the Acrobat Reader Uhull!

Comment: Note: Using Preview is much better than Acrobat because Preview will automatically close and open the new version.