# Why did my TeX-related GUI program stop working in Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: lyx, mac, texworks, sublime-text, rstudio

For example, TeX Live Utility 1.17 and earlier will not work on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite. If a shell task relies on the `PATH` environment variable to launch a command, rather than a fully-specified path, it will likely fail. A typical error message will look like this:

```
/usr/texbin/updmap-sys: line 30: exec: updmap: not found
```

This can also occur in programs that launch `pdflatex`, `dvipng`, `epstopdf`, or other commands as part of a typesetting process.

Comment: Just a note that Apple has done this kind of thing before, and I would not even be sure they will think it is a bug. There was a whole mess with fork() a few years ago that broke all kind of programs, including, if I remember correctly, Adobe Reader.

Comment: @RichardHeck I agree that Apple may not fix it, but since `char **environ` is part of [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/envvar.html), it's hard to see how they'd claim it's not a bug. Enforcing an `exec` after `fork` is the only recent issue I recall in this regard, but at least that had been documented for years beforehand.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Background

There is a bug (or possibly multiple related bugs) in Yosemite with respect to environment variables. When a program is launched in Finder by double-clicking, it will inherit a default set of environment variables from its parent process (I believe this is `launchd` currently, but that's not relevant).

**GUI programs do not inherit variables from `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` or other shell init files.**

TeX Live Utility allows the user to add TeX binaries to its internal (i.e., in-memory) `PATH` variable by means of a preference setting. Other programs may do via shell scripts, config files in the home directory, or other configuration mechanisms.

## Problem

Traditionally, UNIX programs store environment variables in the global variable `environ(7)` (to see documentation, type `man 7 environ` in Terminal). Values in this C-array are generally changed with calls such as `setenv(3)` and read with `getenv(3)`. Child processes launched with `fork(2)` and `execv(3)` will inherit the parent's `environ` variable, although some variants such as `execve(2)` allow passing a different set of environment variables.

When you call `setenv("PATH", "/usr/texbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin", 1)`, it should replace the existing `PATH=…` value in the environment array. Under Yosemite, it appears to either append another `PATH` variable, or fail to modify `environ` at all. Consequently, even though `getenv(3)` may return a correct value, dereferencing the `environ` variable will return something with duplicate values or stale values…in other words, garbage.

## Workaround

For TeX Live Utility, the workaround was to launch it from the Terminal as follows:

```
/Applications/TeX/TeX\ Live\ Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/TeX\ Live\ Utility
```

Note the backslashes to protect spaces in the program name; this is the actual binary, which resides inside the `.app` bundle. The same thing should work for other GUI programs, so please add a comment if it does or does not.

### Caveats

- This workaround may only work with the `bash` shell
- This workaround will certainly only work if `echo $PATH` contains the path to your TeX binaries (for MacTeX, this is `/usr/texbin`)
- If you're writing code, it appears that `environ(7)` is unusable now, and you need to build your own environment and pass it to `execve(2)` or `execle(3)`

### Alternatives

This is clearly a bug, and Apple needs to fix this problem in Yosemite. [TeX Live Utility 1.19](https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/releases/tag/1.19) has a workaround that does not require launching from the Terminal, so I've used it here for illustrative purposes only. The Cocoa `NSProcessInfo` object can be used to get a seemingly correct environment, which can be modified and passed to `NSTask`. Note that `NSProcessInfo` is not thread-safe on all versions of OS X, and this workaround relies on Cocoa picking the "correct" environment variable.

Alternate workarounds may involve [using `launchctl` to set environment variables](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201688563-Problem-with-Mac-Yosemite-Beta-and-RStudio-not-finding-TeX-distribution). I do not recommend setting this up as a default except as a last resort; it modifies the environment for **all** programs you run, and can cause problems that are extremely difficult to debug in future (as Mac OS X's `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` used to do).

Inspired by @JoeCheng in the comments, I also wrote a plain C workaround, in the [diff here](https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/commit/d6e63c2f1844a9aa4e11112d1e3314d4c0c59155). This should be a lowest-common-denominator for OS X.

## Additional

More details and a link to an example Cocoa program to test this can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/issues/detail?id=102). Related problems can be found under the RStudio and Sublime-Text tags.

Any Cocoa program that uses `NSTask` (a wrapper object for `fork/exec`) to launch a shell or other script appears to be affected. This includes Python, for instance; the problem isn't limited to the C/Objective-C language, as far as I can tell. The problem was extremely difficult to debug as things work correctly when you launch from a debugger in Terminal, or launch under the debugger in Xcode. If I have made wrong inferences, that is a likely cause!

I filed a bug report with Apple, two months before Yosemite was released. The only feedback was a request that I describe how what I was seeing was unexpected. I'll update this if I hear anything further.

Comment: excellent explanation. It would be nice to link to the bug report (if there is one). Or perhaps Mac bug reports aren't public? That would be a shame.

Comment: Sadly, bug reports aren't public, since they may have confidential info and so forth. Apple claims that duplicate bug reports count as votes, though I have my doubts.

Comment: Please follow-up if there is a fix from Apple. (I may hold off upgrading. I don't use the GUI Tex programs, but Tex isn't the only application I use that might be affected by this.) I didn't find any other place this was reported with a quick Google search.

Comment: Another work of "cutting edge technologies and innovation" by Apple. WTF, I am pushed to the edge and will never buy a Apple product again. Money has corrupted it to the root.

Comment: Hi, I'm with RStudio. Thanks Adam for such a great writeup, it was very helpful!

We've spent a lot of time investigating this issue and have one additional piece of information that may help. It appears that under Yosemite, the GUI processes in question **start** with two PATH variables (and several others) in the environ block. setenv/getenv affect the first one that's found, but when child processes are launched, they inherit the last one (or at least not the first one--I've only tested cases where n=2). (continued...)

Comment: Until Apple fixes this issue (if they choose to at all) I believe the best workaround for apps like RStudio and Lyx is to immediately remove duplicate env variables at startup. [Here's](https://github.com/jcheng5/envmunge/blob/master/src/munge.cpp#L47-L71) an implementation in C++. Once you've done this, everything is sane again.

Comment: @JoeCheng Thanks, that's a good note; I did a lot of testing with this, and ended up being unsure of exactly what's happening with getenv/setenv vs. environ or when the extra vars get added. It cost me a lot of time to debug and work around; hopefully any inaccuracies in my analysis didn't make things worse for you! Feel free to add your comments as an answer, since my code workaround requires Objective-C.

Comment: @JoeCheng I passed on RStudio's fix to our Mac developer but he explains why LyX needs to do something different (see here: http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg185626.html). His fix is here: http://git.lyx.org/?p=lyx.git;a=commitdiff;h=9574d680e2e15094ba8173c28f1fa4c46c473fe3;hp=31b7a6ba94819e312e343ce771018f11e22f75c3   We will release LyX 2.1.2.1 soon, which contains only this fix.

Comment: I'm not sure his assessment is accurate. We don't have to do this fixup before each fork/exec--we do it once in the GUI process itself, and then fork/exec, popen, NSTask, etc. all behave sanely for the rest of that process's lifetime. I'm happy to discuss more via email at joe@rstudio.com. And also we have a slightly better fix [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/5b8448b80f273c64dd5f18284ffe0f5b3de7617f/src/cpp/desktop-mac/Utils.mm#L234-L280) (just uses posix APIs to mutate the environment instead of pointer manipulation directly on the char**).

Comment: @JoeCheng I wonder if the lyx environment is already set up and/or mutated by Qt before they call fork/exec? I didn't see where they remove duplicates in the link @scottkosty provided, but I'm not much of a C++ guy. My only concern with setting up a clean `char **environ` is that I don't trust Apple not to muck it up later, but I take a similar risk using `NSProcessInfo`.

Comment: Oh and @scottkosty the fixes from our codebase in the message you linked, are all obsoleted now. The one I linked [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/5b8448b80f273c64dd5f18284ffe0f5b3de7617f/src/cpp/desktop-mac/Utils.mm#L234-L280) is totally different, in that it attacks the problem at its source (fixing the parent's corrupted env table) rather than downstream when spawning children. Please, try to get your dev to take a look at this link, it's far superior than messing with environments at fork time and I would be very surprised if it didn't work for Lyx.

Comment: @JoeCheng I will pass that along. Thanks a lot Joe!

Comment: Apple has released an update to Yosemite (10.10.1): http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6572 .  Can anyone speak to whether or not this issue was addressed? (There was nothing obvious in the notes I linked too.)

Comment: @dedded This issue has not been fixed in 10.10.1.

Comment: This kind of thing is one reason I'm a refugee... (Actually, I probably count as a happily naturalised citizen by now since asylum was easily come by...) 'How is this unexpected?' ??!!!

Answer (score 0):

An anonymous user edited my answer as follows:

> It works for AlphaX, version 8.2.2; type: open -a AlphaX in your terminal.

I'm moving this to a separate answer, as this solution does *not* work for the problem as posed (for TeX Live Utility or other programs I've tested). If it does fix a problem for AlphaX, great.