# TikZiT issues (Mac OS X Yosemite)

Tags: tikz-pgf, mac, preview, wysiwyg

I was wondering if people here using the TikZ editor TikZiT are experiencing issues with said tool after upgrading to OS X Yosemite? I can't get it to compile a preview, and I am not able to see the TikZ code anywhere in the GUI. I have followed the online TikZiT manual.

My MacTeX distribution is 2014, my TikZiT version is 0.8 (0.8.417). Whenever I hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, TikZit will only show a greyed out preview window. Any ideas? I'd be also thankful for any pointers to other TikZit WYSIWYG-style editors that are known to run under Yosemite.

[image: sample graph]

[image]

Comment: Since this is Yosemite, try launching TikZiT via the command line, as shown [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208182/61839).

Comment: @AdamMaxwell Thanks - I just tried this. Terminal shows an error when I try to compile my preview image: `CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.`

Comment: Does it work, though? Sometimes CoreAnimation warnings are relatively harmless (or it could be an Apple problem). Since you're using MacTeX, make sure `/usr/texbin` is in your `$PATH` when launching in Terminal.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell Yes - I made sure `/usr/texbin` is in my `$PATH` when I tried this. Still, nothing. I ended up copying over an example from texample.net and contacting the author of TikZiT about the problem. Waiting to hear back from them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used the following workaround:
I renamed **TikZiT.app/Contents/MacOS/TikZiT** to **TikZiT.app/Contents/MacOS/TikZiT-bin**
and created the executable file TikZiT.app/Contents/MacOS/TikZiT with the following content

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=/usr/texbin/:$PATH
exec ${0%/*}/TikZiT-bin
```

It is working for me.