# LyX: Available Citations and .bib files list on Ubuntu is blank

Tags: bibtex, lyx, citing

LyX seems to be having trouble accessing my .bib files.

Precursor info: I use a Thinkpad L450, with the LyX Version 2.1.4, on Ubuntu. I use Mendeley for literature management.

I find that I can't insert citations after adding a Bibliography and bibtex-files. the bibtex files appear when I click on the bibliography button in lyx, but they are not available if I go "insert/citation". the list of available citations is completely blank. If I go to click on the box representing the bibliography to add a source, I see my .bib filename still there.

This problem has been solved here on a Mac, but I do not know how the solution applies to me:

[LyX: 'Available Citations' (and .bib files) list blank](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208714/lyx-available-citations-and-bib-files-list-blank/208731#208731?newreg=5771f9d560fe4ad89c06bcdc7e8da984)

I do not know what it means to reconfigure or run Lyx from terminal. (I know what it means to run Lyx from the terminal in Ubuntu, but that makes no differences regarding the problem).

In addition, sometimes I cannot add further bibtex files (e.g. that are stored on my desktop) to the bibliography. Lyx simply does not recognizes the available file, hence I cannot select it.

Comment: Reconfiguring is probably Tools --> Reconfigure in LyX.

Comment: Running from terminal may provide more information regarding error messages, which may occur with your bibtex files. LyX takes the correct format more serious than many other Bib programs do, in my experience, so maybe this can help you further.

Comment: Thanks! After reconfiguring, LyX now allows me to access all bibtex-files I imported and choose from the list when I go "insert/citation".